# Sony Pictures Imageworks is missing an s on StackOverflow Explore Cities

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, wording

Go to the Vancouver page on [StackOverflow Explore Cities](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cities/vancouver?f=e). The company [Sony Pictures Imageworks](http://www.imageworks.com/) is written as Picture rather than Pictures in the blurb.

> [image]

Comment: Ooh, not quite a pluralisation bug... Does this qualify for bludgeoning anyone?

Comment: Beware of *[Jeff Atwood's Big-S](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791)*.

Comment: Why is this declined? Can someone write an answer?

Comment: @Max care to explain why you declined?

Comment: Didn't seem important enough at first glance- but alright, seems like you guys care. Fix coming...

Comment: @Max you should know us better! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed! The missing s has been added.

Comment: Watch out - people might think you are doing localization fixe now.

Comment: @MichaelT nah, only if encoded entities will appear in there. ;)