# Wrong conjugation of "need" in Stack Overflow Careers house rules

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, grammar

[Stack Overflow Careers house rules](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/house-rules) contains the following line in the Job Listings section

> Multiple positions need**s** to go into multiple job listings.

The conjugation of the verb need is incorrect, the sentence should be

> Multiple positions need to go into multiple job listings.

Comment: "NO JEFF. NO. Put that S away ... this is not a plural."

Comment: Don't just throw that perfectly good **s** away either, you can rehome it here [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251893/sony-pictures-imageworks-is-missing-an-s-on-stackoverflow-explore-cities) where it will be cherished rather than complained about.

Comment: Sorry. I wrote that and I have terrible grammar skills. I'll have someone update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch.

Thanks for the report! :)